# What does the store command do in python? (not the magic %store command)

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I accidentally entered `store` in my ipython console. Specifically `store df`. I meant to enter `%store df`, to store the data of a dataframe into memory, but I forgot the leading `%` character, the one that invokes magic commands.

Recalling the data with `%store -r df` still worked, but when I entered `store` command again, I got a list of apparently stored dataframes, some of which I must have stored ages ago:

```
Stored variables and their in-db values:
df                   ->         A  date  y
doc                  ->         B  ZZZZ
```

What's going on?

Comment: Often magic commands can be run without the `%`.  So I'd expect `store` and `%store` do the same.  This can be turned off, but I suspect your setup allows it.  I don't use `%store` much, but for the magics that I do use I don't need `%`.  I do use `%%` for the cell versions.

Comment: According to the `%store` help, without arguments it `Show list of all variables and their current  values`.  So yes, you are seeing all the variables you have saved.  There's probably a way of deleting or resetting the storage.

Comment: Deleting them is the plan, the question now is how.

Comment: Have you looked at `%store?` the docs?